# How can I perform migrations using my test database context implementation?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, testcontainers

I'm creating integration tests against an API using a dockerised database. Normally I'd resolve the database context and run `context.Database.MigrateAsync()` to set up the database before each test executed. [An example of that is here](https://github.com/NickLydon/DatabaseIntegrationTestSample/blob/main/IntegrationTests/ApiTests.cs#L50-L55).

In another test I want to intercept the call to `SaveChangesAsync` to verify what happens when there are concurrent updates to the database. The API depends on the real [SampleDbContext](https://github.com/NickLydon/DatabaseIntegrationTestSample/blob/main/Database/SampleDbContext.cs), whereas the test injects a fake [TestDbContext](https://github.com/NickLydon/DatabaseIntegrationTestSample/blob/main/IntegrationTests/ApiConcurrencyTests.cs#L64-L77).

However if I resolve the fake context in my test setup, it isn't associated with any migrations (I assume because they are linked to the *real* context implementation). This has forced me to perform the migration synchronously in the call to [ConfigureTestServices](https://github.com/NickLydon/DatabaseIntegrationTestSample/blob/main/IntegrationTests/ApiConcurrencyTests.cs#L29-L32).

Performing the migration synchronously like this doesn't feel right, which leads me to two possible solutions:

**How can I perform migrations using my test database context?**

*or*

**How can I have both the real and test database context classes registered in the IOC container so that it works in the tests and API simultaneously?**

Comment: why don't you use in-memory database for your tests? of course you can fake a real database by in-memory sql server and use it, so all your problem will be fixed

Comment: The in-memory implementation doesn't give me confidence that the application is working as it should. I want to test that the migrations and constraints, etc. work correctly